# IndentationError: unexpected indent - Using Variable in a String

Tags: python

```
#Using Variables in Strings
 firstname="John"
 lastname="Smith"
 fullname=f"{firstname} {lastname}"
 print(fullname)
```

Just started learning Python today and can't seem to figure out why I can't do this line of code(yes I know that indentation is important with Python). Without the indentation for everything below my note, everything runs smoothly.

Comment: The error message is pretty spot on here. there should be no indentation, but there is clearly some whitespace at the start of each line of code

Comment: what code editor are you using?

Comment: Is there any code above the comment that is not indented? Indentation needs to be consistent throughout the whole file.

Comment: "Without the indentation for everything below my note, everything runs smoothly." - well, that's exactly why you "can't do this line of code": because it's indented, in a place where it must not be - which is exactly what the error message told you. "(yes I know that indentation is important with Python)" - well, this is exactly why. I don't understand how there was any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, indentation matters a lot. It tells if your code is in say an `if` statement. Example:

```py
# This works
if True:
    print("Hello, world")
# This doesn't
    print("Hello, world!")
```

However, having indentation outside of an `if else`/`try except`/`def`/etc gets an error. Python uses indents to see if you're in one of those, which is why you get your error. In most other languages it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, indentation is important with Python.
You have space at the start of each line.
You need to delete them so that the code looks like this:

```py
firstname="John"
lastname="Smith"
fullname=f"{firstname} {lastname}"
print(fullname)
```